# Hiawatha and Drupal

Tags: drupal, hiawatha

I posted this on serverfault as well, but I probably asked in the wrong group.

I am using the Hiawatha web server and running drupal on a FastCGI PHP server.
The drupal site is using imagecache and it requires either private files or clean urls.
The issue I am having with clean urls is that requests to files are being rewritten into index.php as well.

My current config is:

```
UrlToolkit {
    ToolkitID = drupal
    RequestURI exists Return
    Match (/files/*) Rewrite $1
    Match ^/(.*) Rewrite /index.php?q=$1
}
```

The above does not work.

---

Drupal's apache set up is:

```
<Directory /var/www/example.com>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are missing the "Return" value for your rule:

```
UrlToolkit {
    ToolkitID = drupal
    RequestURI exists Return
    Match (/files/*) Rewrite $1 Return
    Match ^/(.*) Rewrite /index.php?q=$1
}
```